# Assigning sequential values to a ID column in Sql server

Tags: sql, database

I was sitting in an interview recently and the person evaluating me asked me to write a script for following scenario. According to him, he has imported a Database from some other system which contains a table named Employees. Now there are three columns in that table which are Emp_Name, Age and Salary but this table doesn't have an ID column. He asked me to write a script which will add ID column in the table and then a single update statement for updation of ID column with sequential values( first record starts from 1,2,3 and onwards). I added the ID column but could not write the update statement and even after a week gone, i still can't figure out how i can achieve that. Any idea on how i should go about that?

Comment: Do you mean `IDENTITY` column ?

Comment: i also thought for identity column but he was asking for something out of blue. An update script.

Comment: So , what about Robert McKee's script ?

Comment: just tried Robert's script and that is working fine. Thanks a lot guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE employees
SET id=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees e2 WHERE e2.Emp_Name < e1.Emp_Name)+1
FROM employees e1
```

Only if that fails (duplicate names) would I then add a second condition to the subselect to also add in age and possibly salary to differentiate the records.

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick question.  You can't counjour up actual employee numbers from this air so this ID is just a surrogate key.  Create your new ID as an IDENTITY (SQL Server) and it will be populated for you.  Order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table Employees
add EmpID int Identity(1,1)
```

Try this it should work.

Comment: I also went the auto increment identity column but that gentleman wasn't satisfied att all.

Comment: did you try it in first place Waseem, i posted it only after trying.

Comment: well i think your script is pretty good but the interviewer wasn't asking for identity column. I think he meant something like Robert's script.