# How can I fill a table column with sequential values?

Tags: sql, firebird

What would be the SQL statement to fill an integer field FLD with sequential values 0,1,2,3... in the records?

It's an existing and filled table in a Firebird database with a primary index on another field, but that primary index field has non-sequential values unrelated to FLD.
There are currenlty no limitations on FLD and it should stay that way. Previous values can be overwritten.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/

Comment: @Dan I need a one-time query to update column values in an existing table. I cannot change the behaviour of column FLD. (Updating with I mean with 'No limitations')

Comment: row_number() function seems what you are looking for

Comment: @zinking "update table set fld=row_number()" fails??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it after some more searches (thanks to the answer in [Assigning sequential values to a ID column in Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648958/assigning-sequential-values-to-a-id-column-in-sql-server)):

```
UPDATE tt_calendar c1
SET tt_taskindex=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tt_calendar c2 
WHERE c2.tt_calendar_id < c1.tt_calendar_id)+1
```

tt_calendar is my table name
tt_taskindex is the FLD to update
tt_calendar_id is the primary key field

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence if your database supports it and then:

```
update TABLE set FLD = SEQUENCE.nextval;
```

Be sure to reset the sequence if you run the command again.